# linux hosts.deny ALL EXCEPT not working

Tags: linux

I have added this line to hosts.deny file `/etc/hosts.deny` to allow only access to our apache server from selected address but it does not work for me. any suggestion where I am wrong?

```
ALL EXCEPT: 192.168.3.169
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you've got the exception the wrong side of the colon, that is to say, in the daemon_list half of the entry, not the client_list half.  Try

```
ALL:  ALL EXCEPT 192.168.3.169
```

or to make this apply only to the web server (and assuming that apache consults these files, which I'm not sure is a given)

```
httpd: ALL EXCEPT 192.168.3.169
```